# Adding and dividing variables in bash. error: TEST3=: command not found

Tags: bash, variables, disk

SO I am making a program that tests the average REad/Write speed of the hard drive using the dd command and my code is as follows(bash):

```
a=1
b=1
numval=3
for i in `seq 1 3`;
do
        TEST$i=$(dd if=/dev/zero of=speedtest bs=1M count=100 conv=fdatasync)
        #I think that this is the problem line
done
RESULT=$(($TEST1 + $TEST2))
RESULT=$(($RESULT + $TEST3))
RESULT=$(($RESULT / $numval))
echo $RESULT > Result
```

The code above returns the following errors (in between the dd outputs):
    TEST1=: command not found
    TEST2=: command not found
    TEST3=: command not found

Please help (believe it or not) this is for a school project
 edit: I understand that my variable does not have a valid name. but Im wondering if there is a way to do this without this shit: "^$({$-%})$" REGEX? is there way to do it without that?

Comment: Make sure to mark the correct answer right if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (at least) two problems.

1. `TEST$i=...` is not valid bash syntax for a variable assignment. And if the first "word" in a command line is not a valid assignment, then it's treated as a command name. So `bash` goes ahead and substitutes the value of `$i` for `$i` and the output of the `dd` command for `$(dd ...)` (see below), ending up with the successive "commands" `TEST1=`, `TEST2=` and `TEST3=`. Those aren't known commands, so it complains.

   In an assignment, the only characters you can put before the `=` are letters, numbers and `_` (unless it is an array assignment), which means that you *cannot* use parameter substitution to create a variable name. (But you could use an array.)
2. You seem to be assuming that the `dd` command will output the amount of time it took, or something like that. It doesn't. In fact, it doesn't output anything on `stdout`. It will output several lines on `stderr`, but `stderr` isn't captured with `$(...)`

Answer (score 0):

First problem: you can't use a variable name that's defined in terms of other variables (`TEST$i=...`) without jumping through some special hops. There are several ways around this. You could use the `declare` command (`declare TEST$i=...`), or use an array (`TEST[i]=...` and then e.g. `RESULT=$((TEST[1] + TEST[2]))`), or what I'd recommend: accumulate the times as you go without bothering with the numbered TEST1 etc variables:

```
numval=3

result=0
for i in `seq 1 $numval`; do
    test=$(dd if=/dev/zero of=speedtest bs=1M count=100 conv=fdatasync)
    result=$((result + test))
done

result=$((result / numval))
```

(Note that I prefer to use lowercase variable names in shell scripts, to avoid accidentally using one of the shell's predefined variables and making a mess. Also, inside `$(( ))`, variables are automatically replaced, so you don't need `$` there.)

However, this still won't work because...

Second problem: `dd` doesn't output a number. In fact, it doesn't output anything to standard output (which `$( )` captures). What it does is output a bunch of numbers and other such things to standard error. Your version of `dd` is a bit different from mine, but its stderr output is probably something like this:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1m count=100
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes transferred in 0.011789 secs (8894645697 bytes/sec)
```

... and you presumably want to pick out the bytes/sec figure. Depending on your `dd`'s exact output, something like this might work:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1m count=100 2>&1 | sed -n 's/^.*(\([0-9]*\) bytes.*$/\1/p'
8746239457
```

What this does is redirect `dd's` error output to standard output (`2>&1`), then pipe (`|`) that to a somewhat messy `sed` command that looks for something matching "(", then a bunch of digits, then " bytes", and outputs just the digits part.

Here's the full script I wind up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
numval=3

result=0
for i in `seq 1 $numval`; do
    test=$(dd if=/dev/zero of=speedtest bs=1M count=100 conv=fdatasync 2>&1 | sed -n 's/^.*(\([0-9]*\) bytes.*$/\1/p')
    result=$((result + test))
done

result=$((result / numval))
echo "$result" >Result
```

Comment: So if I want to get the average write speed of a hard drive wouldent "time cp file /~/llamas/blahblahblah/derpittyderp/othershit"? and then Could i just average the output of that? (I would do this about 1000 times)

Comment: Suppose you take a trip of 100 kilometers (or 60 miles, if you are that way inclined). On the way out, you achieve 100 km/h (60 mph). Combing home, you encounter a lot of traffic and you only manage 10 km/h (6 mph). Was your total average speed 55 km/h, the average of 100 and 10? I don't think so. You took 11 hours to go a total of 200 km.

Comment: @Multinotserp: capturing the output of `time` is even harder than capturing `dd`, I'd stick with `dd`. Also, if you copy a small file many times, you may run into trouble with buffering (i.e. you may be measuring the speed of the buffer, not the speed of the disk).

Comment: @rici: "Average" is ambiguous -- it might mean "[median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average#Median)", or "[mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average#Mode)", or "[arithmetic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average#Arithmetic_mean)", or any number of other things... and it also might be weighted in any number of ways. In your example, 55 km/h is the mean weighted by distance (you travelled 100 km/h for 100 km, and 10 km/h for 100 km); and 18 km/h is the mean weighted by time (you travelled 100 km/h for 1 hour, and 10 km/h for 10 hours, so the 10 km/h leg has a much higher weight).